# Optimizing NumPy finite differences via chain rule

Tags: python, numpy, gradient, derivative, finite-difference

Consider the following code:

```
x = np.array([1, 5, 6, 10])  # an unstructured coordinate
f = x**2                     # function value on the points x
grad1 = np.gradient(f, x)                # df/dx
grad2 = np.gradient(f) / np.gradient(x)  # df/di * di/dx = df/dx
```

I would have expected that, by chain rule,  `grad1=grad2`. The `i` in the comment above is simply a uniform "index"After testing, this equality is true for simple linear functions, but not e.g. `x**2` as shown above. I'm now wondering if there is a theoretical reason why the chain rule shouldn't hold in general for derivatives estimated by finite differences.

I think the problem lies in the follow observation:
`np.gradient` does not, in general, assume the input coordinates `x` to be uniform. But I think this expression of the chain rule does, which I suspect is implicit in the call `np.gradient(x)`. When we call `np.gradient(f, x)` with nonuniform `x`, we are really performing an interpolation for each interior point, rather than a true centered-difference...

Comment: Does my answer explain why you shouldn't expect the chain rule to work for non-uniform spacing?

Answer (score 0):

No, I would not expect `grad1` to equal `grad2` for non-uniform spacing. The second-order central difference equation for the first derivative with non-uniform spacing is shown in the [`np.gradient`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html) documentation. When you don't specify the spacing, numpy assumes a constant spacing (as you've said) and makes use of the simplified formula that goes with that assumption, i.e. `f' = (f[1:] - f[:-1])/(2h)` (ignoring the endpoints). When you attempt to perform the derivative as you have done, you end up with `f' = (f[1:] - f[:-1])/(x[1:] - x[:-1])` (again ignoring the endpoints). This is not equivalent to the non-uniform equation since the weights are incorrect. Therefore, your results are wrong.